# Need help in slight building a logic for modifying the files in sub-folders using Bash script

Tags: bash, yaml, swagger

I am trying to modify the set of YAML files & Swagger YAML files using bash script to avoid manual copy paste work.

My directory looks like below :-

```
C:.
├───folder-1
    ├─── README.md
    ├─── dev.yaml
    ├─── prod.yaml
    ├─── qa.yaml
    └─── run.ps1
├───folder-2
    ├─── README.md
    ├─── dev.yaml
    ├─── prod.yaml
    ├─── qa.yaml
    ├─── run.ps1
    ├─── sample.yaml
    ├─── swagger-1.yaml
    └─── swagger-2.yaml
```

I wanted loop over folder-1 , folder-2
And edit all dev, qa, prod YAML for appending some text
and all swagger.yaml in another appending

Here is my beginning level of script

```
for d in *; do
 echo $d
 cd $d
 ls -l
 cd ..
done
```

With above script I am only able to list all folders and its files.
I need help how do I append the file ? for just an example, I wanted add 'dummy' as content in each of target files.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for d in *; do
 echo $d
 cp -a ./resources/. ./$d/
 
 cd $d
 
 for f in *.yaml; do 
    if [[ "$f" = kong* ]]; 
    then
     yq e -i '._info.select_tags = [.services[].name]' $f
    else
     yq e -i '(.security.gas-oidc = []) | (.components.securitySchemes.gas-oidc.type = "oauth2") ' $f
    fi
 done
 
 echo "Files are modified now pushing to git repository"
 git add .
 git commit -m "Batch for commit in git"
 git commit
 git push origin master:dev

 cd ..
done
```